# MySQL - trying to get unique key on a long-ish text field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a constraint in MySQL by member, date and question so that the same user cant ask the same question more than once a day.

```
alter table questions add UNIQUE INDEX three_UNIQUE ( member_id , question , date );
```

but since the question field is long text, i get this error:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

any way to get around this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't usually make much sense to specify a unique key constraint on a user entered long text field. The user can still ask the same question more than once, simply by adding a space or making some other minor change.

If your intention is to prevent *accidental* reposts then use a hidden field with a GUID or similar unique identifier.

Comment: ye my intention is to prevent doing it by accident. How/when do I generate the guid?

Comment: @Genadinik: You can generate a unique identifier on the server (e.g. a GUID) and add it into the form as type "hidden". When you get the postback you insert this same value back into the database. If the form is posted twice, the second time will fail.

Comment: great, last question...what should be the data type in the database for the guid? just varchar?

Comment: char(16) (or other such constant depending on how long your guid is) would be more optimal

Comment: btw, what if there are existing records in the db, how do I add the unique index? there will be an error that the index is same for existing rows, no?

Comment: @Genadinik: Make the column nullable.

Comment: @MarkByers So you are saying a long unique row is impossible in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

You could hash the question, and store the hash value as a field. Since the hash value will be much smaller, you'll be able to add a constraint on that. In all likelihood, no two unique questions will hash to the same value.

Note: you'll have the same issues with this as you would when the questions only have minor differences.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column for hash (md5, or whatever). When the question is asked, populate the hash column as well.. then use that in your index instead of the question field.